# Convexity of the optimal value function

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose we have the optimal value function as:
\begin{align}
v(x) = \max_{y\geq 0}\,&c^\top y\\
s.t. \,&g(x,y) \leq 0.
\end{align}
If we know $g(x,y)$ is linear in $x$, but nonconvex in $y$, is $v(x)$ a convex function? If no, under what conditions on $g(x,y)$ such that $v(x)$ is convex in $x$? (I know for sure that if $g(x,y)$ is also linear in $y$, $v(x)$ is convex.)